# Software Testing

Tags: functional-testing

After completion of the testing process in a software product, there is no defect.. then what is our next step??

Comment: As soon as I finish some software with no defects, I'll let you know what happens next.

Answer (score 6):

2. Ship it
3. Profit

Comment: Not to mention moving on, and identifying if one can continue milking the cow, or start a new product.

Answer (score 1):

You never can say without lying "There is no defect", you just can say "No defect has been revealed by our testing process".

Your next step is to prepare the shipping. This involves:

- write user's manuals and software reference documents
- create a payment service for shipping your product and receiving money
- create a customer service for handling feature requests and bug reports
- write v2.0 and V1.xx in parallel

Answer (score 0):

1. Product Release
2. Revenue